# Returning a document and its path in a hierarchy using RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, hierarchy

I am using RavenDB for the first time as a database for a website. I am just starting out and thinking about how to represent the page website hierarchy in the database. I read this article [Modelling hierarchical data with RavenDB](http://code972.com/blog/2014/01/769-modelling-hierarchical-data-with-ravendb) and it shows a really neat way of storing a hierarchy in a document database and hence I am running with this design.

So I have my Page document

```
public class Page
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

and my PagesHierarchy document.

```
public class PagesHierarchyTree
{
    public class Node
    {
        public string PageId { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Node> RootPages { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is to have the PagesHierarchyTree represent the tree and this document has reference id's to the actual documents.

So, now to my question. I want to create an index where I can find a document (page) based on the slug but also return the slug path i.e a/b/c based on where the document lives in the tree.

I read about [Indexing Hierarchical Data](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/indexing-hierarchical-data) and [Indexing Related Documents](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/indexing-related-documents) but i`m struggling to bring them together.

Can someone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just come across loading, including and dealing with hierarchical data in transformers. Hmm....I wonder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from the ravendb google groups forum found [here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/d4HaAZKFIgE)